# Dynamically address HTML elements with JavaScript, relative to the triggering object

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website

I wrote a Responsive Website with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. On the desktop, the dropdown-menus in the menu are triggered via the CSS :hover event.
On the Mobile version, those menus collapse via a JavaScript event. I have two divs in the menu, which open dropdown-menus. With unique onclick events, a collapse class is added and removed to the items, via GetElementById.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-link" id="parentone">
        <!--link for the first parent menu-item-->
    <a class="menu-link" href="parent-one">Parent One</a>
        <!--div for the first dropdown-arrow-->
    <div class="dropdown-klick" id="parentonearrow" onclick="parentonedropdowntoggle()"></div>
        <!--div for the first dropdown-men-->
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="parentonedropdown">
        <a class="menu-link" href="parent-one/item-one">Dropdown One Item</a>
        <a class="menu-link" href="parent-one/item-two">Dropdown One Item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Code for toggling the adressed menu with unique events.
function parentonedropdowntoggle() {
  document.getElementById("parentone").classList.toggle("parentopen");
  document.getElementById("parentonearrow").classList.toggle("dropdownclose");
  document.getElementById("parentonedropdown").classList.toggle("dropdownopen");

//Code for closing the other dropdown-menu, when opened
  document.getElementById("parenttwo").classList.remove("dropdownclose");
  document.getElementById("parenttwoarrow").classList.remove("dropdownclose");
  document.getElementById("parenttwodropdown").classList.remove("dropdownopen");
}
```

Both sections of code exist another time, to do the same actions for the second item in the menu, which has a dropdown. It does work for my site for now but obviously is extremely inflexible and not really usable, when a new one is added.

How can I use a single event, which assigns the class via JavaScript, to the div, that triggered the event?

I did not find any solution, when I searched my question on the internet. I was looking for something like this:

```
function dropdowntoggle() {
  document.getElementByTriggered("menu-link").classList.toggle("parentopen");
}
```

A method, which would address the div with the class in the brackets, that triggered the above event. Am I on the right way, to achieve my goal?

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure but if you are asking how to, inside the event handler, get the element that triggered the event: you might just use `this` or better (in my opinion and because is more flexible) having your event handler the argument `event` and inside use `event.target`.

Comment: event.target and event.currentTarget